# Unable to run CefSharp Browser

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVGT0.png)

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
File name: 'CefSharp.Core.dll'
   at _Browserium.Browserium.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)




************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4250.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
֍Browserium
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/kbbar/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/R2MLKWG0.95C/9OGMTXDP.PVX/brow..tion_0000000000000000_0001.0000_2592dcd67c817531/%D6%8DBrowserium.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4270.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4200.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4190.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4270.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
CefSharp.WinForms
    Assembly Version: 86.0.241.0
    Win32 Version: 86.0.241.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/kbbar/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/R2MLKWG0.95C/9OGMTXDP.PVX/brow..tion_0000000000000000_0001.0000_2592dcd67c817531/CefSharp.WinForms.DLL
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Tried adding all CefSharp Files

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSIQK.png)

Is there anything else i could do to fix this issue

I have gone through other stackoverflow related to this but couldn't find a solution. Starting the app in Visual Studio works.
I also edited the .csproj and added this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="$(SolutionDir)packages\dll\**\*.*">
      <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need the Visual C++ runtime.

I had similar problem and installing the vcredist package fixed it.

More details can be found here:

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#Including_vcredist